# Firing event on DOM attribute change

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events, dom-events

Is there any way to trigger event (may be custom) on attribute change?

Let's say, when IMG src is changed or DIV's innerHtml?

Comment: An query plugin would do that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781778/detecting-attribute-change-of-value-of-an-attribute-i-made/29978836#29978836

Answer (score 53, accepted):

*Note: As of 2012, Mutation Events have been removed from the standard and are now deprecated. See other answers or documentation for how to use their replacement, [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).*

You are referring to [DOM Mutation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents). There is poor (but improving) browser support for these events. [Mutation Events plugin for jQuery](https://github.com/jollytoad/jquery.mutation-events) might get you some of the way.

Comment: DOM mutation events are actually reasonably well supported among browsers. It's just that IE doesn't support them at all (although IE 9 will).

Comment: @TimDown if it comes to IE, it's not a strange thing.

Comment: These are now deprecated in favor of `MutationObserver`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: For me this answer is too succinct. I couldn't find out how to use the plugin for jquery. But the answer of Mats is simple and there's no need for extra plugin.

Answer (score 42):

How to setup a MutationObserver, mostly copied from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but I've added my own comments for clarity.

```
window.MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver
    || window.WebKitMutationObserver
    || window.MozMutationObserver;
// Find the element that you want to "watch"
var target = document.querySelector('img'),
// create an observer instance
observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutation) {
     /** this is the callback where you
         do what you need to do.
         The argument is an array of MutationRecords where the affected attribute is
         named "attributeName". There is a few other properties in a record
         but I'll let you work it out yourself.
      **/
}),
// configuration of the observer:
config = {
    attributes: true // this is to watch for attribute changes.
};
// pass in the element you wanna watch as well as the options
observer.observe(target, config);
// later, you can stop observing
// observer.disconnect();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works like a charm in Chrome. Really useful!

Answer (score 6):

If you only need something specific then a simple `setInterval()` will work, by checking the target attribute(s) every few milliseconds:

```
var imgSrc = null;
setInterval(function () {
   var newImgSrc = $("#myImg").attr("src");
   if (newImgSrc !== imgSrc) {
      imgSrc = newImgSrc;
      $("#myImg").trigger("srcChange");
   }
}, 50);
```

Then bind to the custom "srcChange" event:

```
$("#myImg").bind("srcChange", function () {....});
```

Comment: usage of intervals for this is really poor in my opinion (Yes it is 'a' way).

Comment: The usage of intervals is appropriate in limited quantities especially where performance won't become an issue. I haven't ran any bench tests but I know from experience I can manipulate all kinds of properties in the DOM in a fast interval without noticing performance degradation.

Comment: The MutationObserver may be a more elegant solution, but what if the element in question hasn't been generated yet?  And for debugging purposes, I think it's ok to let things temporarily be a little messy.  My use-case at the moment is trying to chase down what's responsible for erroneously changing a value in a Legacy system, so this solution actually suits me better than the cleaner one.

Answer (score 4):

There is no native dom changed event you can hook into.

Good article [here](http://darcyclarke.me/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery/) which tries to provide a solution in the form of a jquery plugin.

Code from article

```
$.fn.watch = function(props, callback, timeout){
    if(!timeout)
        timeout = 10;
    return this.each(function(){
        var el      = $(this),
            func    = function(){ __check.call(this, el) },
            data    = { props:  props.split(","),
                        func:   callback,
                        vals:   [] };
        $.each(data.props, function(i) {
              data.vals[i] = el.css(data.props[i]); 
        });
        el.data(data);
        if (typeof (this.onpropertychange) == "object"){
            el.bind("propertychange", callback);
        } else if ($.browser.mozilla){
            el.bind("DOMAttrModified", callback);
        } else {
            setInterval(func, timeout);
        }
    });
    function __check(el) {
        var data    = el.data(),
            changed = false,
            temp    = "";
        for(var i=0;i < data.props.length; i++) {
            temp = el.css(data.props[i]);
            if(data.vals[i] != temp){
                data.vals[i] = temp;
                changed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(changed && data.func) {
            data.func.call(el, data);
        }
    } }
```

Comment: There are pretty huge performance implications with this approach.

Comment: "Good article" link broken :(

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Mats' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22736833/1744774) inspired by [MDN's MutationObserver Example usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example_usage):

If your *options* contain `<property>: true` and you plan to change this property of *target* inside `MutationObserver`'s callback function, use the following to prevent recursive calls – until script timeout, stack overflow or the like:

```
...
// Used to prevent recursive calls of observer's callback function
// From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change
let insideInitialObserverCallback = false

let callback = function(mutationsList) {
    insideInitialObserverCallback = ! insideInitialObserverCallback
    if ( insideInitialObserverCallback ) {

        // ... change target's given property ...       

    }
})

let observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, where I had to find track attribute change of some particular DOM element. and I used MutationObserver.

But there was one more complication what I was facing while using  MutationObserver.
MutationObserver is need some target element while observing change.

while working with SPA (where AJAX, Angular , react or any other javascript framework have been used), you might have realized all the elements are dynamic.
that's it would be difficult to set target.

Here I came with some solution where I have applied MutationObserver on DOM and then emitted customEvent when some attribute of any element gets change.

then in next step filter custom event as per our requirement.

```js
 // code to change image src in each 1000ms.
        count = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            dimension = `${600+count}x${400+count}`;
            document.querySelector('div.image-box img').src = `https://dummyimage.com/${dimension}/000/fff`;
            document.querySelector('div.image-box img').alt = dimension;
            count++;
        }, 1000);

        function startMutationObserver(tNode, c) {
            // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
            const targetNode = tNode ? tNode : document;

            // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
            const config = c ? c : {
                attributes: true,
                childList: true,
                subtree: true
            };

            // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
            const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
                for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
                    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                        targetNode.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('newChild', {
                            detail: mutation
                        }));
                    } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
                        targetNode.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('attributeChange', {
                            detail: mutation
                        }));
                    }
                }
            };

            // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
            const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

            // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
            observer.observe(targetNode, config);

            // Later, you can stop observing
            // observer.disconnect();
        }
        // call this function to start observing DOM element change
        startMutationObserver(document);

        // code to listen custom event and filter custom event as per requirement
        document.addEventListener('attributeChange', function(e) {
            // console.log(e);
            const ele = e.detail;

            if (ele.target.matches('div.image-box img') && ele.attributeName == 'src') {

                var src = e.detail.target.getAttribute('src');
                var alt = e.detail.target.getAttribute('alt');
                console.log(src, alt);

            }
        })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="600x400">
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope this will help you to tracking any attribute change, insertion of new element also..
Lets try, and let me know if you are facing any issues.