# Look where is js code set events for html document

Tags: javascript, html

I have html document and many many js script files. How can i understand where js code set onclick event for element? There are thousands lines of code and look it all is very painfull.

Comment: Search for `onclick` or `click` in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

1. Into [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome), go to the [Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/chrome/devtools/) ;

   - `Menu` > `Tools` > `Developer Tools`
   - Windows shortcut: `Maj` + `CTRL` + `i`
   - Mac OS X shortcut: `Command` + `Option` + `i`
2. Then, in the "`Elements`" section, found the element you are interested in ;
3. After this, on the right; you have a lot of information, like styles, metrics, etc. But if you scroll down, at the bottom, you have a section named "`Event Listeners`"

It references all the events and where they are declared.

You can also direcly access this pannel by right clicking on the element of the page, and choose "`Inspect Element`"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have no ready-to-use solution but this might get you started: There is a jQuery plugin to intercept "DOM Mutation Events" (which include "when an attribute is modified".

[Here are the docs](http://www.adaptavist.com/display/jQuery/Mutation+Events) and [here is to the code](https://github.com/jollytoad/jquery.mutation-events).

If you're not using jQuery, either convert part of your code to jQuery or analyze the code of the plugin to see how it uses these events.

Related questions: [firing event on DOM attribute change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change)