# Implementation of a DOM listener

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, event-listener, dom3

I was thinking there was no DOM listener so I implemented my own 'heavy' listener:

```
function CvHelper(stackApi) {
  var that = this;

  // check if room is finished loading
  this.init = function() {
    if ($('#loading').length) {
      setTimeout(that.init, 1000);
    } else {
      console.log('Chatroom finished loading');

      that.postListener();
    }
  }
}

(function() {
  var stackApi = new StackApi();
  var cvHelper = new CvHelper(stackApi);
  cvHelper.init();
})();
```

I think this just sucks. So I did a search on here on SO and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener) popped up. However the [last comment on the accepted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener#answer-2844704) states that it is deprecated.

```
$("#someDiv").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  alert("tree changed");
});
```

> [w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified) says this event is deprecated, what would we use instead?

Is there a substition for it?
P.S. It only has to work on Chrome, because it is an Chrome extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at:

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MutationEvent

It states that, regarding DOMSubtreeModified, "It may be fired after a single modification to the document or, at the implementation's discretion, after multiple changes have occurred."

Therefore, if you use a different MutationEvent, say DOMNodeInserted, you may get a more deterministic firing of events (You'd just have to add an element to the node in that specific case).

See below:

```
$('body').prepend( $('<div id="cow">Hello</div>') );

$('#cow').bind("DOMNodeInserted",function(){ alert('hi'); } );

$('#cow').prepend( $("<div></div>") );
```

This was tested in Chrome, btw.

Hope that helps...

UPDATE: 
Alternatively, you could add more than one event type in one function call. For example, adding four event handlers for DOMNodeInserted, DOMNodeRemoved, DOMAttrModified, DOMCharacterDataModified, then all of the handlers call a single handler.

UPDATE: I wrote a little script that does what I had just written in the previous update:

```
$('body').prepend( $('<div id="cow">Hello</div>') );

/**
* This function registers event handlers which invoke the mutateHandler 
* handler when any of the MutationEvents are fired on a node: DOMNodeInserted, 
* DOMNodeRemoved, DOMAttrModified, DOMCharacterDataModified.
*
*/
var onMutate = function( mutateHandler ){

    var that = this;
    $(this).bind( "DOMNodeInserted", function( event ){ 
        mutateHandler.call( that, event ); 
    });
    $(this).bind( "DOMNodeRemoved", function( event ){ 
        mutateHandler.call( that, event ); 
    });
    $(this).bind( "DOMAttrModified", function( event ){ 
        mutateHandler.call( that, event );
    });
    $(this).bind( "DOMCharacterDataModified", function( event ){ 
        mutateHandler.call( that, event );
    });

};

onMutate.call( $('#cow')[0], function(){
    alert( $(this).attr('id') );
});


$('#cow').prepend( $("<div></div>") );
$('#cow').addClass( 'my_class' );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "You'd just have to add an element to the node in that specific case"?

Comment: I mean that the event would only fire if an element were added to that node, like in the third line of the sample code. The third line is what causes the event to fire. Whereas, changing the attribute would not cause the event to fire.

Comment: Great I will give it a try. I don't care about chaing attributes. It's added elements to DOM I'm listening for.

Comment: I've created the method that I was talking about before, above.

Answer (score 3):

The [Mutation Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) is currently deprecated because of it's performance issue. Hence, Please use the [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). I did the DOM changes listener in one of my project using Mutation Observer and it worked great! For your further implementation, these links will help you:

1. http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-detecting-new-elements-with-the-mutationobserver-object/
2. https://github.com/kapetan/jquery-observe
3. [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's actually only deprecated in in the working draft of [DOM Level 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents), which provides this note:

> Warning! The MutationEvent interface was introduced in DOM Level 2
>   Events, but has not yet been completely and interoperably implemented
>   across user agents. In addition, there have been critiques that the
>   interface, as designed, introduces a performance and implementation
>   challenge. A new specification is under development with the aim of
>   addressing the use cases that mutation events solves, but in more
>   performant manner. Thus, this specification describes mutation events
>   for reference and completeness of legacy behavior, but deprecates the
>   use of both the MutationEvent interface and the MutationNameEvent
>   interface.

So if I understand correctly, the answer to the question "Is there a substitution yet?" is "no, not yet."

Comment: P.S. Here is another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change