# Detect a img src change

Tags: javascript, image, onchange, src

I'am trying to detect if the source of a image is changed.

In my case the src is changed from jquery, and i have no right's to change the jquery file.
So im trying to detect the src change from a img element.

I would like to see the source if the src is changed, just for testing

This is my current code:

```
var divimg = document.getElementById("img_div");
divimg.onchange = alert(divimg.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src);
```

On the page load the alert react's and shows me the src, but not on a src change from jquery

Comment: Please, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change

Answer (score 22):

```
var img = document.querySelector("#img_div img"),
observer = new MutationObserver((changes) => {
  changes.forEach(change => {
      if(change.attributeName.includes('src')){
        console.dir(img.src);
      }
  });
});
observer.observe(img, {attributes : true});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, now its 2018 the observer method is the way to go!

Answer (score 9):

You could do it, however it would only be supported by new browsers that implement the [DOM mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events)...

```
divimg.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", function(event) {
    if (event.attrName == "src") {
       // The `src` attribute changed!
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Every time the `src` attribute is changed the browser will immediately go off and fetch the image. Once the image is returned to the browser the browser will trigger the `loaded` event on the image element. So you can effectively monitor `src` changing by setting a callback on this event. You could do something similar to the following code example.

```
var img = $("<img />");
img.load(function() { console.log("loaded"); });
img.attr("src", "http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/ecc536e9e1204b7faccb15621f27d7bc.jpg");
```

Answer (score 7):

`DOMAttrModified` might work, no idea about that...but onload works definitely fine for me. Here's the fiddle with the demo. http://jsfiddle.net/QVqhz/

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events this method is deprecated and could cause your site to stop working since this feature has been dropped from the standard.

Answer (score 2):

**Analysis**

1. `load` event is triggered when `src` attribute of `<img />` is changed or set
2. If user didn't write `src` attribute in `<img />`, browser will fill out `src` attribute automatically (*such as data:image/png;base64,...*) to prevent 204 Error. This will also trigger `load` event.

**Conclusion**

1. Basically use `load` event, but check whether it is default image or not. (*Probably, default image would be 1 x 1 pixel*)

   - Assumption - your image is bigger than 1 x 1 pixel

**Solution**

```
$('img').load(function() {
    var imageObj = $(this);
    if (!(imageObj.width() == 1 && imageObj.height() == 1)) {
        console.log('Image source changed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no event for that, you can create your own 'event':

```
var divimg = document.getElementById("img_div"),
    prevSrc;
setInterval(function() {
    if (divimg.src != prevSrc) {
        prevSrc = divimg.src;
        onSrcChange();
    }
}, 1000); // 1000ms = 1s

function onSrcChange() {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Be aware, this solution polls to see whether the `src` attribute has changed every 1 second. That seems very expensive! I cannot believe a polling solution is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that jQuery should always be the way to go because of its cross-browser support. However the ".load()" function has been deprecated since [jQuery 1.8](https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/).

Today we are supposed to use the ".on()" function like the following example:

```
$('img.my-image-class-name').on('load', function(){
  console.log('Hello, world');
});
```

If you attempt to use the ".load()" function, your code will simply not work. You will get the following error message:

> **Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function**