# JavaScript onchange attr event for img

Tags: javascript, html

No jQuery, just JavaScript. I'm using prototype.js but can't find in documentation how can I do that.

I have the img element, and some event that change attr src, so my code is:

```
document.getElementById('image').addEventListener('change', myFunction(), false);
```

but this solution doesn't work with img element!

Comment: Does your image element actually have an ID assigned to it, called 'image'? Please provide more real code.

Comment: yes, document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('color', 'red'); works fine.

Comment: @LubomurMarshal I dont think img element supports onchange event, rather than that you can use onload event.

Comment: IIRC only input/select/textarea elements have an onchange event?

Comment: I think you should try to use `load` instead of `change` (this is not supported by img).

Comment: if jQuery can do this, must be some solution for javascript!

Comment: dont pass myFunction(), pass myFunction

Comment: @user1671639 load what do mean?

Comment: Whenever a image is changed, it will be loaded, so bind it using load event.  Since `change` event supports form elements (IIRC)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `change` event for **`img`** tag.

> The [**`change`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change) event is fired for **`<input>, <select>, and <textarea>`**
>   elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the
>   user.

So try like this whenever a image is changed, it will be loaded, so bind it using **`load`** event.

Comment: That's work! document.getElementById('image').addEventListener('load', qwe, false);

Comment: @LubomurMarshal I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I too am trying to move an old-IE solution using `img` `onchange`, which used to detect change to image's `src` attribute just fine.

However, the `load` event solution here (and similarly in [Detect a img src change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655531/detect-a-img-src-change)), while great for detecting change to a new image, unfortunately does *not* fire if you are setting `src=''` [EDIT: HTML5 does not allow empty, I have changed to use `src='data:null'`] (I guess because there is no image to load). This is a genuine case for me (user can pick "no image"), and I still want to change attributes like `alt` & `title`.  Just a heads-up for anyone else.