# Fire JS-Event just when elements are added

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, dynamic

I want to call a event everytime elements are added. Im using JQuery, which has built-in functions to accomplish adding events to all elements (so also elements that get added later) that match a selector, which looks like this:

```
jQuery("body").on("click", ".selection", function (evt, selector) { passSelectorToOtherFunction(selector) })
```

But unfortunately i don't want to put a "click"-event-handler on it, i just want to know when they get added so i can do stuff with them (without having to do that explicitly after each ajax call).

So basically, i'd need something like a 'ready'-event which is available for all elements, like:

```
jQuery("body").on("ready", ".selection", function (evt, selector) { passSelectorToOtherFunction(selector) }).
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at [liveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)? It should allow you to do what you need.