# Identify the attribute change event in KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dom-events, custom-attributes, knockout-2.0

Is there any way to identify the attribute change event in KnockoutJS?

I found solutions in jQuery:
[Firing event on DOM attribute change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change)
.

But it would be good if I can do it with KO.

Answer (score 2):

If the attribute change is bound to a property in your view model, then you can simply subscribe to that property to get notified of changes.

```
myViewModel.myProperty.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("This property changed!!");
});
```