# How to invoke a function onChange of an atrribute value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to invoke a function `onChange` of an attribute value. 
What I'm trying is, When the user clicks on one of below div

```
 <div id="selected" class="vblock">
 <div class="vblock">
 <div class="vblock">
 <div class="vblock">
 <div class="vblock">
```

The value of `src` attribute of `embed` tag will be changed.

```
<embed id="vplayer" width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="resources/videos/xyz21.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

I need to invoke a function during the change of `src` value.

or

I need to invoke the function during the modification of `<div class="vblock">` to `<div id="selected" class="vblock">`

What I tried is :

```
$('embed[src=#]').change(function(e){
 // code
```

Please anyone help me to do this stuff...Thanks.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My thougth on this problem:

1). You would better close your `div`s.

2). Instead of `<div id="selected" class="vblock">` you should use `<div class="vblock selected">` this is what classes for.

3). You can't listen attribute changes (well you can, but mutation events are deprecated anyway..), but you can manually trigger your event handler:

```
$('.vblock').on('click', function() {
    // do something, set new src
    $('#vplayer').trigger('src:changed');
});

$('#vplayer').on('src:changed', function () {
    // src changed, do something
});
```

Comment: But there is no response for `$('#vplayer').on('src:changed', function () {` event... I can't do anything on click event. Because I'm adding `id=selected` during the `click` event. Using this `id` I'm retrieving some values. If I use click event It will result null.

Comment: But the same code is not working for me. Is there any way to make `delay` the execution of a function. Like `delay(1000)` in `java`.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { alert('Delayed'); }, 1000);`

Comment: Thank You sir `setTimeout(function()},time);` worked for me.. Thank you very Much........