# How to get notified when attribute value of a control is dynamically set or changed in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to have event delegation like behavior when control's attribute value is set or changed.

i.e. Code like below should call a function
`$(controlSelector).attr('attrName','value');`

```
$(input,select,inputarea).delegate('attributeNameToWatch','EventType',function(){});
```

I add custom attribute dynamically in my code.

I tried the above code with my preferred attribute name and EventType as "change" but it does not trigger when I add , set or change attribute value.

Comment: This should be the answer to your question :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change