# Get notified if an HTML attribute changes in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to get notified about changes in attributes of a specific HTML object? I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change) thread but it's is only about *normal* DOM in browsers, I want this for a Chrome extension.

Edit: I just realized that Mutation observer is the thing I want. I thought this is only available via jQuery. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutationObserver) for further resources.

Comment: So what is the question? use mutation events.

Comment: Well, yes. You're right. I thought this is just available as a jQuery plugin. I put the answer into my question. Thanks!

Comment: Please avoid Mutation events (`DOMAttrModified`). Use Mutation Observers instead.