# Play a css3 sprite animation once and hold on the last frame

Tags: html, css, animation

I have an sprite animation that I would like to play once, finish, and hold on the last frame. I've tried changing the iteration count to 1 and added forward to the fill mode but neither worked. Any information or ideas would help.

I'm using this css3 sprite method. http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/light/

`-webkit-animation: crouch 1.2s steps(2, end) 1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the Fill Mode is for. Add the `both` keyword to your animation definition and, when the animation stops, it should "freeze" at the last frame and stay that way.

EDIT: Ah, I see what's going on. The animation in that example is actually going one frame too far. You need to change the `to` keyframe to `-450px` and lower the number of steps to `9`, as well as adding the `both` keyword.

Note that `-ms-animation` has never existed, and neither `-o-animation` or `-moz-animation` are neede anymore. It's just `animation` and `-webkit-animation`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to stop the animation on the last frame without some javascript (or you could simply use a sprite animation toolkit.

You need to use javascript to:

1. Test if style applied to element `background-position` == 500px. This may or may not be straight forward. Can we fire an event on attribute changed using javascript? If not then you will have to test it repeatedly using a timer
2. Set the `animation-play-state:paused` on the above condition using javascript.

OR:

You can find some sprite animation scripts out there which will no doubt allow far more control over the animation.

UPDATE:

To make the tesing of the attribute easier (without the use of setInterval - it uses some nice tricks - you can use a plugin for jQuery.

There is a [SO question about mutation events here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change)

Comment: Yes, it made sense and led me to interesting librarys. However, it didn't solve my issue directly.