# jQuery - Detect dialog div addition to dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am working on an Enterprise app. I need to style certain pop-ups that are shown in application. I found that whenever a popup is shown following div is added to the body.

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="ui-id-12" aria-labelledby="ui-id-13" style="position: absolute; height: auto; width: auto; top: 263px; left: 626px; display: none;">
```

The idea is to detect when this popup is added and then add classes to it as per my need. To accomplish that and for this I am using following code

```
    $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted',"div.ui-dialog", function(e){
        console.log("Dialog Div Added");
    });
```

But this is not working.

Please Help

Comment: what about document.load ?

Comment: sorry can you provide an example of what you mean by document.load

Comment: I mean $(document).on('load','div.ui-dialoog',function(e){

Comment: document on load didn't work as the dialog is added later as a result of an user action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the DOMSubtreeModified event. For example:

```
$(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
  console.log("now there are " + $('a').length + " links on this page.");
})
```

Or

```
$(document).on('DOMAttrModified',function(){
  console.log("now there are " + $('a').length + " links on this page.");
})
```

Or

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted',function(){
  console.log("now there are " + $('a').length + " links on this page.");
})
```

You can see more events to use here: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents and see which one works better for you.

Comment: shouldn't I be using on instead of bind?

Comment: I used DOMNodeInserted instead of above mentioned events as it triggered fewer times than DOMSubtreeModified.

Comment: @Neel I also added the DOMNodeInserted in my comment just to make it more complete in case anyone needs it.

Comment: Don't forget the thumbs_up ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about dom mutation event handling.
have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4561975/2478038