# jQuery - how to trigger a function whenever a element enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to fix my function to work, whenever the element enabled. at present it's not working..

here is my try:

```
var x = function () {
    input = $('#username');

    if (input.prop('disabled')) {
        console.log('i am enabled'); //  how to trigger this?
    }
}

x();

$('#enable').on('click', function(){
    $('#username').removeAttr('disabled');
})
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/T6arW/)

Note: my App always remove the attribute `disabled`

Comment: when you want to disable?

Comment: On load all elements are disabled. some reason I am clicking on a button, it makes the total form elements are enabled ( removing prop ), on the time i would like to fire a function..

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/T6arW/1/

Comment: or check with this http://jsfiddle.net/T6arW/3/

Comment: Your question is not clear to me but anyways if you need to fix ur function, then here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/T6arW/5/

Comment: this should help you check  DOM Mutation Events this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle (modified your fiddle) Hope this is the solution you require

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6arW/6/)

Code Snippet:

```
if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
    console.log('i am disabled'); //  how to trigger this?
}
```