# Jquery, real time "title" attribute change

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have a span that shows some datas in tooltip every second that comes from server:

```
<span class="bata hastip" title="{will change}"></span>
```

And I'm using [tooltipsy](http://tooltipsy.com/) plugin to show tooltip:

```
$('.hastip').tooltipsy({
        offset: [-10, 0],
        css: {
            'background-color': '#444F54',
            'border': '1px solid #888'
        }
})
```

Since my data change every few second, how can I detect that change? like this:

```
$('.bata').prop('title', datas);
//$('.bata').attr('title', datas) same...

$(document).on('change', '.bata', function(){
   //this method doesn't work
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [firing event on DOM attribute change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change)

Comment: I solved my problem using that link, thanks!

Comment: You must have very fast comms to have a real-time update once per second! Thrashing a server like that is unusual :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It's just array of online users :) Not much.

Comment: You may poll a bit less often nevertheless :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"You are referring to DOM Mutation Events. There is poor (but improving) browser support for these events. Mutation Events plugin for jQuery might get you some of the way."*

See this related question : [firing event on DOM attribute change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change)

Shortcut - check this :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Support's pretty good, except IE11+

Example usage from MDN :

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```