# html dialog - how to know if the dialog was closed with escape

Tags: html, dialog

I'm using the dialog tag in html, and I would like to know when the dialog was closed if it was closed by entering ESC.

I'm talking about the html dialog and not the dialog of jquery.

Answer (score 2):

HTML dialog element has `close` event that you can listen for
More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/close_event

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger an event when the dialog's open attribute changes using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Code derived from [Mats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1958257/mats) answer to [firing event on DOM attribute change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change)

```js
window.MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;


var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
var btn = document.querySelector('#open-dialog');

var observer = new MutationObserver(onDialogMutation);

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

  dialog.showModal();
  observer.observe(dialog, {
    attributes: true
  });
});

function onDialogMutation(mutation) {

  observer.disconnect();
  console.log('Dialog Closed');
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Dialog MutationObserver</title>
</head>

<body>
  <dialog>My Dialog</dialog>
  <input id="open-dialog" type="button" value="open dialog" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a really good implementation, but for some reason, I couldn't get it to work in React. In React I couldn't differentiate between opening or closing the dialog, though this may be my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can recognize key events in javascript. You can do the following:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) { // do something };
});
```

KeyCode 27 is escape.

Comment: But it will invoke for every escape in the dialog, even if I press escape on lets say a combo box inside a dialog, which is not really what I want