# How to pass 'responseText' from an XMLHttpRequest function call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have code that I would like to return straight text, that has been read from a text file (happens to be JSON in this instance, but may not always be in future) and I would just like to pass the results back from a function call. The text, or sections thereof will eventually be displayed on the web page. See next bit of code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Not Working Example</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="myfunction()">
        <div id="demo1" onclick="loadDoc()">demo1</div>
        <div id="demo2" onclick="loadDoc()">demo2</div>
        <div id="demo3" onclick="loadDoc()">demo3</div>
        <script>
            var dataString = "Test";

            function loadDoc() {
                var string = readDoc("TestData.json");
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = string;
                document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = dataString;
            }

            function readDoc(fileName) {
                var fReader = new XMLHttpRequest();
                fReader.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                       dataString = this.responseText;
                       document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                fReader.open("GET", fileName, true);
                fReader.send();
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a function (readDoc) that simply returns a data string (see line 14), but I am having issues passing the responseText to either a global variable or a result back to the invokation on line 14 & line 22. What am I doing wrong?
Unlike line 24, I don't want to write straight to an HTML element as I want to manipulate the data first (in a separate function), before displaying. The (temporarily simple) example of "TestData.json" is...

```
{
    "DataValue": 33
}
```

I have tried lots of different permutations but can't seem to manage to get the desired result. Some 'genioid' out there is going to say "ahh, easy I can seem what the idiot has done wrong.", but I can't see the woods for the trees.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous, so while your code will update `dataString`, there's no way to know when this occurs programatically, unless you change your code to handle the nature of asynchronicity.

Answer (score 0):

Is readDoc really get the result? Have you check the result? Can you check using console.log or alert?

I think the issue is you need hidden type input for the result, but you better make sure that you get the desired result in the readDoc first.

Comment: As far as I can tell it is! The 'document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText; on line 24 populates the HTML element correctly as the string is correctly displayed on the web page. As for the 'hidden type' I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Oh I see the problem is it an asynchronous

Comment: As far as I know you need a notify dataset change. You can try [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change). Hope this help.