# How to make my text stick to a responsive div?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am having issues making my text stick to responsive images like this:
https://cloud.screenpresso.com/S8N5c/2019-10-11_16h25_59.png

I have tried changing the `position` in CSS.

You can check my source code in https://eylenkim.github.io/ArtByEylen/

When you drag the screen, the text also moves away from the responsive images.

But here's a snippet:
    ```HTML

````
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

      <div class="one-half column u-pull-left">
        <a href="Shop/shop.html">
          <img data-sr class="homeReveal u-max-full-width duo-pic" src="photo/artbyeylen13.JPG">

          <div class="overlap-text">
            <div class="overlap-text-outline">
              <h2 class="load">Enter Shop</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="overlap-text-base">
              <h2 class="load">Enter Shop</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="one-half column u-pull-right">
        <a href="Portfolio/portfolio.html">
          <img data-sr class="homeReveal u-max-full-width duo-pic" src="photo/artbyeylen11.JPG">

        <div class="overlap-text">
          <div class="overlap-text-outline">
            <h2 class="load">Portfolio</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="overlap-text-base">
            <h2 class="load">Portfolio</h2>
          </div>
        </div>

        </a>
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section> 

```
````

````
    .overlap-text h2{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        opacity: 1;
        letter-spacing: .1px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .overlap-text.is_active h2{
      transform: translateY(-25%) scale(1.15);
      top:45%;
    }


    .overlap-text-outline h2{
      font-family:'GT-America-Extended-Black';
      font-weight: 800;
      font-style: normal;
      color: transparent;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 1.4px #fff;
      z-index: 7;
      font-size: calc(5em + 1vw);
    }

    .overlap-text-base h2{
      font-family:'GT-America-Extended-Black';
      font-weight: 800;
      font-style: normal;
      color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
      background-clip: text;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      background-image: url(otherCss/noise.gif);
      -webkit-text-stroke: none;
      z-index: -4;
      font-size: calc(5em + 1vw);

      -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
      transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    }
    ```
````

Comment: make your text child of the moving object and do the position absolute to this object. Then he has to follow. Otherwise use javascript to figure out where the moving object is Based on that calculate the position of the text. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change.

Comment: @ThomasLudewig dude I have no idea what you said in your first sentence.

Comment: <div1><class="c1"></p><div1><style>p{position : absolute;left :100px:top:100px}</style> Sorry but i am not a native english talker. My german is on the othe rhand not that bad :D